# How to prove below?

Tags: conditional-expectation

Given 
\begin{split} 
A =~& \theta(X) \cdot D + g(X) + \epsilon ~~~&~~~ \mathbf E[\epsilon | X] = 0 \\
D =~& f(X) + \eta & \mathbf E[\eta \mid X] = 0 \\
~& \mathbf E[\eta \cdot \epsilon | X] = 0 
\end{split}
How to prove below?
\begin{split} 
   A - \mathbf E[A | X] = \theta(X) \cdot (D - \mathbf E[D | X]) + \epsilon
\end{split}

Comment: Please, provide context (what are the variables? what is $\E$? etc.), add informations in the title,  and also write what have you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbf E[\epsilon |X] = 0, \mathbf E[\eta | X] = 0$, by linearity of expectation we have \begin{align}
\mathbf E[D | X] & = \mathbf E[f(X) | X] + \mathbf E[ \eta | X] \\
& = f(X) \\
\mathbf E[A | X] & =  \mathbf E[\theta(X) \cdot (f(X) + \eta) + g(X) + \epsilon | X] \\
& = \theta(X) f(X) + \theta(X) \mathbf E[\eta | X] + g(X) + \mathbf E[\epsilon | X] \\
& = \theta(X) f(X) + g(X) \\
& = \theta(X) \mathbf E[D | X] + g(X) \\
A - \mathbf E[A | X] & = \theta(X) \cdot D + g(X) + \epsilon - (\theta(X) \mathbf E[D | X] + g(X)) \\
& = \theta(X) (D - \mathbf E[D | X]) + \epsilon
\end{align}

I don't think the assumption that $\mathbf E[\eta \cdot \epsilon | X] = 0$ is necessary.